# Which one is right "I have talked to him, and he gave me some advises" or "I have talked to him, he has given me some advises"

Tags: present-perfect

Which one is right:

> I have talked to him, and **he gave me** some advises.

or:

> I have talked to him, **he has given me** some advises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use "gave" as it refers to the specific occasion which is in the past.

However, take care with the word "advice". As a noun it is uncountable. The verb form is "advise".

Answer (score 2):

Both forms of the verb are perfectly correct. Which one you preferred would probably depend on the context.

If your conversation with him had taken place recently, you would probably say: **he has given me some advice**, especially if the advice was still relevant to your decisions and actions.

If your conversation had been held some time ago and the advice related to something in your past - how to obtain a visa for example - you would say: **he gave me some advice**.

It's simply a question of context and preference.

Note that while he might **advise** you (verb) what you receive is **advice** (noun - always in the singular)